# Changing an object's attribute in a list during iteration with Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, object

In Python, I'm trying to use nested for loops in my script to iterate over a list of object attributes.  The iterated copy of the attribute resets during nested iteration.  How can I modify the referenced object's attribute so that it doesn't reset?

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, index, name, rating, sex, team, bench):
        self.index = index
        self.name = name
        self.rating = rating
        self.sex = sex
        self.team = team
        self.bench = bench

player1 = Player(1, "jasan", 971, "male", "MK", True)
player2 = Player(2, "Jaimen", 972, "male", "MK", True)
player3 = Player(3, "Jessica", 973, "female", "MK", True)
player4 = Player(4, "Justin", 904, "male", "MK", True)

opponent1 = Player(1, "Marc", 91, "male", "OPP", True)
opponent2 = Player(2, "Tom", 92, "male", "OPP", True)
opponent3 = Player(3, "Josh", 93, "male", "OPP", True)
opponent4 = Player(4, "Randy", 94, "male", "OPP", True)

mkroster = [player1, player2, player3, player4]
opproster = [opponent1, opponent2, opponent3, opponent4]

for x1 in mkroster:
    for y1 in opproster:
        x1.bench = False
        y1.bench = False
        for y2 in opproster:
            for x2 in mkroster:
                if x2.bench and y2.bench:
                    print(x1.bench, x2.bench)
                    match2 = matchup(x2.rating, y2.rating)
                    print("Round 2", x2.rating, y2.rating)
                    x1.bench = False
                    y1.bench = False
                    x2.bench = False
                    y2.bench = False
                    for x3 in mkroster:
                        for y3 in opproster:
                            if x3.bench and y3.bench:
```

How can I modify the object attribute (`player1.bench`) to match the iteration value (`x.bench`)?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it's crucial to get it right in Python.

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of `"john`

Comment: Assigning to `x.bench` should do what you want. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I copied / pasted some of the actual code.  There's a lot more nested iterations, but I'm trying to make the player attributes equal to the iteration attributes.

Comment: @barmar Is it readable now?  The code has been executing correctly, it's just that x.bench resets to True for outer iterations.  I want it to hold, preferably by changing the object attribute.

Comment: Your code runs, but copying it and checking any of the objects confirms that bench is set to false after running it. Can you provide an example of where it remains set to true?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz I've pasted more of the code (it continues for 4 nested for loops).  When it gets to the nested iterations, they use the original roster, so the change in x1 isn't reflected in x2, x3, etc.  So I think I need to modify the original roster list for it to stick.  Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to completely change my approach and not use the for loop?

Comment: This for-loop is looking like a huge antipattern in general. I'm not completely sure what you're looking to achieve but I can guarantee there's a far more elegant way to do it. That said: it is working as expected. Maybe replacing the print statement with print(x1.name, x1.bench, x2.name, x2.bench) will make it clearer what's going on.

Comment: Why are you looping through the same lists 3 times?

Comment: I think what's causing the confusion is all these nested loops. So an inner loop may be processing a player before the outer loop has set their bench to False. Why don't you just set everyone to False at the beginning?

Comment: `for x in mkroster + opproster: x.bench = False`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to do the work of the for loop. Like Chris Schmitz said, it looks like an anti-pattern. Check out [this](https://beginnersbook.com/2018/01/python-for-loop/) for a better idea of how the for loop assigns each value in your list to the variable, for instance, x1.

[EDIT] I'm not exactly sure what your code is trying to do, but here is a snippet and an explanation of some code that might help:

```
mkroster = [...]

opproster = [...]

for x1 in mkroster:
    for y1 in opproster:
        print(x1.name, y1.name)
```

What this code snippet prints out is

```
jasan, Marc
jasan, Tom
jasan, Josh
jasan, Randy
Jaimen, Marc
...
```

so x1 and y1 are already being assigned to each player object one at a time. If you want to have more complicated bracket that isn't just the roster in order you will need some more firepower.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to change the value in my list to equal the variable?  I'm guessing I need to track what iteration I'm on (what player in the roster) and then assign that player to = x1 somehow.  I'm just not sure what command I can use to do this.

Comment: @Patrick - it sounds like you might have an idea of how to address this. If so, could you modify your answer with some alternate code that may help solve the original poster's problem?

Comment: My full code is a match-up algorithm.  In essence two teams alternate in snake order putting up players.  The player with the higher rating wins.  The algorithm will run through every possible combination to figure out what player is best to put up each round.  There is a lot of code that I need to make the details happen, but the crux of my issue is I want the "bench" attribute of each player to change once they are used.  This way, they aren't reused in the subsequent matchups.  As such, I need a way to change an object's attribute in a list from the iteration for loop.